# Multiple Broken Relays -- What About My Circuit Is Making Them Fail?

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

I recently purchased one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C8O9KHA) relay boards ...

[image]

to use along with my Raspberry Pi to switch an AC outlet on/off to control a fountain pump. Since the relay board requires 5V for the control lines and needs to pull more current (IIRC) than the RPi can supply on 5V, I put together this little circuit to test out my system:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsXEOf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Relay Schematic:
[image]

I know that my "To Relay Control" line is only going to pull down to ~.3V when the RPi GPIO is high, but it was enough to toggle the relay, so I went with it.  I have software that turns the pump on 15 minutes out of every hour, and the system was functioning fine for a few hours.  However, after a few (~8) hours of operating the relay is no longer switching -- even if I pull the "To Relay Control" line directly to ground the relay will not flip into the "on" position.  I thought this might have just been a random bad part, but I switched to another relay on that board and had the same problem after running fine for a few hours.  The LED on the relay board lights up when the line is pulled low, but that's it, I don't hear a "click" out of the relays anymore when I toggle them.

Is there something about my test circuit that is causing these relays to fail?  In general, what would cause a relay to fail in the manner that I've described?

Comment: The unlabelled arm of the relay coil is connected to +5 V?

Comment: What's the point of connecting the normally closed on the relay to anything? Maybe you're frying (eg. welding) the relay contacts. How much watts/horsepower does the fountain pump draw? Motor loads can be unfriendly to cheap relay contacts.

Comment: What voltages are connected to the pump? The schematic only says 'ACin' and 'ACout'. How much power is the pump? Also, why are both positions of the relay connected? For 'on/off' it only needs one side connected.

Comment: @ThePhoton the relay coil is connected to *something* in that relay control board that is driving the relay.  I haven't looked at that board's schematic yet, but I'll fill in that blank when I do.

Comment: Also, looking at the Amazon listing, it looks like there is some 4-pin "chip-looking-thing" between the input signal and the relay. It's possible that this is an optocoupler and your "To Relay Control" signal isn't actually connected to the relay coil at all.

Comment: Seems to be similar to the relay board discussed [here](http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/ArduinoPower) (scroll down a lot) which has optical isolation...

Comment: Do you have a snubber in the system? Does the damage occur if you drive an *unloaded* relay for, say, 24h cycles?

Comment: @gbulmer I'm using [this](http://www.amazon.com/PonicsPump-PP12005-Submersible-Fountains-Aquariums/dp/B006M6MSL0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1450804456&sr=8-1&keywords=fountain+pump) pump.  The AC is 110V from the wall outlet.  I connected the "off" position to AC- out of digital design habit (read: it felt right).

Comment: @pjc50 I'll give that a shot; thanks for the suggestion.  A snubber seems like a reasonable thing to add to the design.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Is there a way I can determine if the relay contacts have been welded?

Comment: @Adam sacrifice one and open it up.

Comment: If your pump provides power right after disconnection from mains (i.e. it turns from a motor to a generator powered by its inertia), connecting its two terminals via relay contacts may "weld" them in that position. Even if you power the coil, the contacts will not change anymore. Can you check the coil's continuity to verify if it is open? If it is not, then probably is some type of contacts being "glued" problem.

Comment: Motor loads can be quite harsh on relays (right, that's been said.) What can be switched for a resistive load (amps) is far above what can be switched for a motor load. Probably better to leave the unused contact floating, this is not digital.

Comment: @Adam - One way to check for welded contacts is to use an ohm meter to see if NO to COM leads are shorted when the relay has no coil voltage. Similarly check the NC and COM leads whilst the relay coil is energized. An alternate way is to open up the relay case and take a look at it.

Comment: If the power to a normal relay is disconnected and the relay does not show continuity with the N.C. and open to the N.O. contacts then the contacts have been damaged.

Comment: It looks like the consensus and the posted answer are 1) Disconnect the AC from the NC port of the relay and 2) use a snubber.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

1. Get rid of the extra AC connection on the relay. This contact set could weld themselves if an inductive load were present and the contacts were shorted like that.
2. For inductive load add a snubber across the relay contacts to help protect the contacts from welding.
3. I took the liberty if showing the AC source correctly and not as + and -.

Comment: point 1, that extra circuit also means an arc is directly across the supply.

Comment: Four months later and my relays are still running!  This answer solved my problem.